# JMS non-MDB client

Tags: java, jms, messaging

I want to subscribe to the JMS queue with no usage of EJB MDB. The reason is that I want to receive messages only when I want, but not automatically.
Is there some ways to implement it using plain Java (no Spring or smth else)?
I use WebLogic and its internal JMS provider, if it is important.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to connect to your JMS Queue of your Application server. JMS is a quite good standard, so after getting your Connection/Queue, the implementation is Vendor agnostic.

Here is a short overview what you have to write to create a consumer/producer with JMS: [JMS Sample](http://www.javafundu.com/2010/01/jms-sample.html)

This shows each step in detail with WebLogic JMS: [Developing a WebLogic JMS Application](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/jms/implement.html)

I didn't used WebLogic or it's JMS implementation, maybe you have to configure Weblogics JMS: [Configuring and Managing WebLogic JMS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/jms_admin/index.html)

For a comprehensive overview of the programming capabilities of your WebLogic JMS Provider, look here: [Programming WebLogic JMS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/jms/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I will have a look today, but I guess that's pretty much the thing I need.